# Project nightclubs C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

Hi everyone i am building a project in C# which contains records of night clubs. A user will be able to search for a night club through their criteria which criteria could be: The music that the night club plays or the drinks that nightclub offers e.t.c..
I am building a form application which form contains 4 comboboxes which a user can set their criteria to search for a nightclub and a datagridview that shows the records of a database but i am having the following problem take a look at my code:

```
public partial class KirioMenou : Form
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = c:\users\dim\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Eksatomikeush\Eksatomikeush\Xrhstes.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
    SqlDataAdapter ad;
    public KirioMenou()
    {          

        InitializeComponent();
        fillcombo();
    }
    // this is a logout button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 ss = new Form1();
        ss.Show();
    }

    private void KirioMenou_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'xrhstesDataSet.Magazia' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.magaziaTableAdapter.Fill(this.xrhstesDataSet.Magazia);

    }
     void fillcombo()
    {
        //Type
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Club");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Bar");
        //type of music        
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Rock");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("House");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Elliniki");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("Industrial");
        //place
        comboBox3.Items.Add("Aigaleo");
        comboBox3.Items.Add("Peristeri");
        comboBox3.Items.Add("Gazi");
        comboBox3.Items.Add("Peiraias");
        //kind of drink
        comboBox4.Items.Add("beer");
        comboBox4.Items.Add("All");
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Whiskey");


    }
    //this is the button that i call the "showdata()"
    //Also the form contains a textbox if someone wants
    //to search a nightclub by name
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            showdata();   
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Magazia WHERE Onoma='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
            ad.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }

    }
     //and this is just a reset button of comboxes and textbox
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Magazia", con);
        ad.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        comboBox1.Text = "";
        comboBox2.Text = "";
        comboBox3.Text = "";
        comboBox4.Text = "";

    }

    void showdata()
    {

        //declare parameters
        SqlParameter paraType = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paraMusic = new SqlParameter("@Music", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paraPlace = new SqlParameter("@Place", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        SqlParameter paraDrink = new SqlParameter("@Drink", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        //append the parameters
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text))
        {
            paraType.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            paraType.Value = comboBox1.Text;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
        {
            paraMusic.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            paraMusic.Value = comboBox2.Text;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text))
        {
            paraPlace.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            paraPlace.Value = comboBox3.Text;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox4.Text))
        {
            paraDrink.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            paraDrink.Value = comboBox4.Text;
        }

        //construct the query
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Magazia WHERE Type = @Type AND Music = @Music AND Place = @Place AND Drink = @Drink";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraType);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraMusic);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraPlace);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paraDrink);

        //get the data and put it into the datagrid
        dataGridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //tidy up
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

When i execute my program it does not work as i desire...For example if i set in the combobox1 during runtime the word "Club" the datagridview will correctly select the cells that contain the word "Club" of my database. But when i set a value in other combobox such as combobox4 the datagrid view will show the nightclubs that contain a specific kind of drink it is like that it forgot that i selected "club" in combobox1 i know that this is how it supposed to work with that kind of code but i want the datagridview will show the records that contain "Club" and "Beer" for example. I thought using a commandline such as:

```
"SELECT Count(*) FROM Nightclubs WHERE Type='" + combobox1.Text+"'and Drink='"+combobox4.Text+"'",con );
```

But i still have to include a lot of "if" for combobox2 and combobox3 too to make this work and i am not sure if it is gonna work correctly. Is there an easy way to include all possibilities for a user that searches for a nightclub through from comboboxes ?

appreciated for your help

Comment: The first change you should make is to start using parameterized SQL. Next, it looks like you'll probably want to build the SQL dynamically in terms of your WHERE clause... or (preferrably) use LINQ which makes this sort of thing easier. You could potentially have a single where clause which has something like `WHERE (music=@music or @music is null) and (place=@place or @place is null) ...`

Comment: Add a variable: private ComboBox lastUsedComboBox;  Now you can write your showdata() method correctly.

Comment: @hansPassant Can you be more specific in what i can succeed using LastUsedComboBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your code runs, you are setting the data source of the data grid to a new set of data, which means it will remove the old data. What you need to do is instead of treating each combo as a separate query, join them up into 1 and then set the data source.

Something like this should do the trick but it DOES rely on your columns containing no nulls!

```
void showdata() {

    //declare parameters
    SqlParameter paraType = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter paraMusic = new SqlParameter("@Music", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter paraPlace = new SqlParameter("@Place", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter paraDrink = new SqlParameter("@Drink", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    //append the parameters
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text)) {
        paraType.Value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
        paraType.Value = comboBox1.Text;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text)) {
        paraMusic.Value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
        paraMusic.Value = comboBox2.Text;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text)) {
        paraPlace.Value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
        paraPlace.Value = comboBox3.Text;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox4.Text)) {
        paraDrink.Value = DBNull.Value;
    } else {
        paraDrink.Value = comboBox4.Text;
    }

    //construct the query
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Magazia WHERE Type = @Type AND Music = @Music AND Place = @Place AND Drink = @Drink";
    com.Parameters.Add(paraType);
    com.Parameters.Add(paraMusic);
    com.Parameters.Add(paraPlace);
    com.Parameters.Add(paraDrink);

    //get the data and put it into the datagrid
    dataGridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();

    //tidy up
    com.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: first all don't you have to use the command "con.open()"? I edit that in your code because it could not let me run it...Also when i push the button that i have set to show the records in datagridview when a combobox text is not empty it shows nothing...and when i try to press again the same button i got this error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my snippet. Can you post your full code for this button please as I feel there is something missing from your original post that is causing this issue.

Comment: I've updated the code with 1 small difference i have replaced your "com" with "cmd" because my "cmd" is my SQLcomand type thank you a lot for your time

Comment: probably it has something to do with "construct query" part code but the thing is that it seems alright as a logic to show data. Also i have deleted the lines "cmd.dispose()" and "con.Dispose" because Dispose method is to release unmanaged resources used by the application and i don't want that anyway this sovled the problem with the "The Connection String Property has not initialized" but the blank datagridview remains...